# Django: BASE_DIR not correct after the os.path.join(...) command

Tags: django, python-3.x, path, settings, environment

I am getting the following behavior in Django:

BASE_DIR seems to change when I use the "**os.path.join(...)**"  command on it.

My settings.py file:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

In the Python Shell:

```
>>> import os
>>> from django.conf import settings

>>> base_dir = settings.BASE_DIR
***'C:\\Users\\gille\\timeless_wisdom'***

>>> file_path = os.path.join(base_dir, '/timeless_wisdom/UserData')
***'C:/timeless_wisdom/UserData'***
```

So: when I join a relative path with BASE_DIR, I don't get the expected result, but he starts from C:/ again...

I have tried the following, but same result.:

```
file_path = os.path.join(base_dir, '\\timeless_wisdom\\UserData')
```

I have tried using PROJECT_ROOT instead of BASE_DIR, but same result.

Anything I am missing? Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't have any leading slashes on the path.

```
file_path = os.path.join(base_dir, 'timeless_wisdom/UserData')
```

Comment: Ofcourse... it works. Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score -1):

setting.py

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.file'
SESSION_FILE_PATH = BASE_DIR / 'session'
```

BASE_DIR is another method to add external file to the django inner project - setting.py

The above code store the session data in file which is created in root project file.

FILE_PATH = BASE_DIR / 'Foldername'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35690123)

Comment: `BASE_DIR` is not "_the new method_" the actual point is that in newer versions of Django the generated settings file uses [pathlib.Path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path) to create that setting which then allows you to use write code like you did.

Comment: well, i have provide you a practical working example from my practical project , django now support FILE_PATH = BASE_DIR / 'foldername' instead of file_path = os.path.join(base_dir, '\\timeless_wisdom\\UserData')